# Method of using getline function and making a program to create a seat list

Tags: c++

I am a beginner of C++ and I was trying to write a program to help operators create a seat list.

Then, I wrote few lines to prompt user to enter Name, passportId, Seat with only one line using the format below:
Name/PassportID/SeatNumSeatChar

The code I paste below was meant to create a temporary Name, PassportId and Seat to see whether it is assigned in the current seat plan, the two dimensional character arrays can match the current seatplan (also two dimensional character arrays) for checking.

If the requested seat location of a particular user in the batch has already been assigned, the assignment addition request of that particular user will be unsuccessful. Only the successful assignment addition requests update the system. (not included in the code)

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int add_Assignment_In_Batch();

int main(){add_Assignment_In_Batch()}

int add_Assignment_In_Batch(){
    
string Name[13][6] = { "none" }, PassportID[13][6], Seat_Num[13][6], Seat_Char[13][6];
    int Row = 0, Column = -1;

   cout << "enter name/passportID/Seat:,until 0/ is entered." << endl;

    do {    //input format: Name/passportID/Seat into array

        if (Column == 5)Row++;
        if (Column == 5)Column = -1;
        Column++;
        if (Row == 12 && Column == 5)break;

        getline(cin, Name[Row][Column], '/');
        if (Name[Row][Column] == "0")break;
        getline(cin, PassportID[Row][Column], '/');
        getline(cin, Seat_Num[Row][Column], ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'));        //input Seat Number,when encounter A B C D E or F,stop getline
        getline(cin, Seat_Char[Row][Column]);

    } while (Name[Row][Column] != "0");

    Column--; //print out all the information below

    cout << endl << "*** Total Requests ***" << endl;
    if (Row != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++) 
            for (int k = 0; k < 6; k++)  //e.g [1][0]Name: Chris PassportID: 123456A Seat: 10A
            {
                cout << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << k << "]   " << "Name: " << Name[i][k] << " PassportID: " << PassportID[i][k] << " Seat: " << Seat_Num[i][k] << Seat_Char[i][k] << endl;
            }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= Column; i++)
        cout << "[" << Row << "]" << "[" << i << "]   " << "Name: " << Name[Row][i] << " PassportID: " << PassportID[Row][i] << " Seat: " << Seat_Num[Row][i] << Seat_Char[Row][i] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Expected input(example):

```
Chris/12345678A/10A
Kyle/24689C/2D
0/
```

`10` is assigned to `Seat_Num` 
`A` is assigned to `Seat_Char`

I end up need to input `ABCDEF` to finish `getline(cin,Seat_Num[1][1],(‘A’,’B’,’C’,’D’,’E’,’F’));`

Expected output(example):

```
[1][0]Name: Chris PassportID: 123456A Seat: 10A
[1][1]Name: Kyle PassportID: 24689C Seat: 2D
...
```

Here's the result of execution:

```
$ ./test
enter name/passportID/Seat:,until 0/ is entered.
Chris/12345678A/10A
Kyle/24689C/2D
0/
0/
0/
0/

*** Total Requests ***
[
```

It did not stop the `getline()` and lets the user keep typing.

I don't have any idea to finish the above statement while the `getline()` encounter A B C D E or F.

Comment: Could you copy/paste the code instead of a picture ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please provide a [mre]

Comment: Can you explain why you have two dimensional character arrays to store strings?

Comment: Note: Google's not much help until you know what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would start again, heres what you need

- define a struct that contains a booking: strings name, passport and seat
- now create an empty vector of those structs
- now loop getting a whole line fronm the user via getline
- chop the line up on the / character and create a new booking entry
- store that entry in the vector